# iOS: Tab change programmatically - storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to change tab programmatically in storyboard but getting error

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

TabViewController *tabBarCon = [storyboard 
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];

tabBarCon.selectedViewController = [tabBarCon.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

Error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Here `tabBarCon.viewControllers` is not empty.

`NSLog(@"%@",tabBarCon.viewControllers);` giving

```
(
"<FirstViewController: 0x16642020>",
"<SecondViewController: 0x173c4c00>",
"<ThirdViewController: 0x166db570>",
"<ForthViewController: 0x166d17c0>",
"<FifthViewController: 0x166066a0>"
)
```

Comment: log shows the crash occurs while inserting nil object to the array. try adding exception breakpoint to detect the exact line that cause crash.

Comment: line `tabBarCon.selectedViewController = [tabBarCon.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];` is crashing

Comment: just say `tabBarCon.selectedIndex=1;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to have instance of tabbarcontroller.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

TabViewController *tabBarCon = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];
```

This statement creates new instance of tabbar from storyboard.

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

If you are within the tab bar controller then you will easily get the instance using `self.tabBarController`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
TabViewController *tabBarCon = [storyboard                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: Have you try to set selectedIndex after pushing or presenting  tabbarcontoller .......

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UITabBarController *controller =(UITabBarController *)     
self.window.rootViewController;
[controller setSelectedIndex:1];
```

i have tried on Appdelegate it is working

Comment: i have put that code on Appdelegate so there is self.window.rootViewController sorry for that

Comment: Second line incomplete

Comment: mean [controller setSelectedIndex:1] ? @Salim

Comment: you can also set [self setSelectedIndex:1] to sub class of your UITabbarController Also working